# Selecting a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

My Questions is: how can I get the value of the selected cell in a `DataGridView`?

here's my code:

```
txtUsername.Text = grdUser.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
DataGridView view
```

To find the row number selected:

```
selectedRowNumber = view.SelectedRows.Count > 0 ? view.SelectedRows[0] : -1;
```

To get the text of the first cell selected:

```
text = view.SelectedCells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

**Take a look at the documentation here:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.FormattedValue
```

Comment: @user714607: I think this is what you are looking for.